# switch activities

Tags: android

Dear All; 
I am really confused in the matter of layouts and activities , I was used on windows applications for forms and classes but here it seems a bit deferent , So I don't know when i will use and layout and when I have to switch activity... any way I have build an sample application and I decided for each activity to have its layout. 
and I want to switch between activities. so I write the code in the AndroidManifest.XML

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.content.intent.ActionBootCompleted" />
             <category android:name="android.content.intent.CategoryDefault" />
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name=".activity1"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN2" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".home"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN2" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

and then In each onclickListener :

```
Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
             //alert.show();
       //  setContentView(R.layout.menu);
         String packageName = activity1.class.getPackage().getName();

       String packageAndClassName = activity1.class.getName();
       Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(packageName,packageAndClassName);
       startActivity(intent);

        }
        });
```

So it is switching between activity to Home but When I want to switch from home to actvity1 it returns me back to activity ...

So what is the problem???

Answer (score 3):

This snippet ought to do a better job of launching your `activity1`. You'll have to rename `MyActivity` in the example to the name of the activity class hosting the snippet (or provide an alternative context variable).

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, activity1.class);
      startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

from AndroidManifest.XML we can see that `activity` is your main activity,so

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(packageName,packageAndClassName);
```

will switch to `acticity`.

try to use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, activity1.class);
```

more:

```
public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

Create an intent for a specific component. All other fields (action, data, type, class) are null, though they can be modified later with explicit calls. This provides a convenient way to create an intent that is intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than relying on the system to find an appropriate class for you;
[reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the topic [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html). It explains the concepts of navigating between activities pretty clearly.